# Intercept TAB key and suppress it

Tags: delphi, keyboard, delphi-7

I need to intercept the TAB keyboard stroke on TEdits and suppress them programmatically.
In certain cases I don't want the focus to change to the next control.

I tried to handle KeyPress, KeyDown both on TEdit level and on TForm with KeyPreview=true.
I've peeked advices from:

- [Intercept TAB key in RichEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104006/intercept-tab-key-in-richedit)
- [How do I make the TAB key close a TComboBox without losing the current position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989384/how-do-i-make-the-tab-key-close-a-tcombobox-without-losing-the-current-position)

But it didn't work.
The events are fired for, let's say, the Enter key BUT not for the TAB key.

I'm using Delphi 7.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: They are not fired because the `TAB`key is intended to be the key which moves focus to the next control, thus it has a special handling.

Comment: Thanks TLama. The behaviour is explained. So do you think, is there an escape route?

Comment: http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2002/a/bltip0702_5.htm

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to intercept the TAB key behavior, you should catch the `CM_DIALOGKEY` message. In this example, if you set the `YouWantToInterceptTab` boolean value to True, the `TAB` key will be eaten:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    YouWantToInterceptTab: Boolean;
    procedure CMDialogKey(var AMessage: TCMDialogKey); message CM_DIALOGKEY;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.CMDialogKey(var AMessage: TCMDialogKey);
begin
  if AMessage.CharCode = VK_TAB then
  begin
    ShowMessage('TAB key has been pressed in ' + ActiveControl.Name);

    if YouWantToInterceptTab then
    begin
      ShowMessage('TAB key will be eaten');
      AMessage.Result := 1;
    end
    else
      inherited;        
  end
  else
    inherited;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Dear TLama, this worked just perfectly. Best cut&paste ever ;)