# EmbeddedWB TAB key

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser, tembeddedwb

I use `EmbeddedWB` in edit mode and need to insert tab (4 * `&nbsp;`) when user presses <kbd>TAB</kbd> key. I've trapped `OnKeyDown` event and did the following:

```
if (Key = VK_TAB) then
begin
EditDesignerMsg.InsertHTML('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
EditDesignerMsg.EmbeddedWB.SetFocusToDoc;
end;
```

The problem is that this moves focus from the control to another control as usual with <kbd>TAB</kbd> in Windows. I want to keep the focus within the web browser control and only move away to previous control if the user presses <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

How can this be done?

Comment: Using `&nbsp;` to insert whitespace is extremely bad practice in HTML. Use CSS (paragraph indent) or a pre-styled block instead.

Comment: To extend my previous (now deleted) comment, you can inspire in [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10470053/960757).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to TLama, I've managed to do this by intercepting CM_DIALOGKEY message and applying the message handler which inserts specified HTML code at that point and then eats the message by setting `AMessage.Result := 1;`. More details how to implement this message handler can be found here:

[Intercept TAB key and suppress it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470053/intercept-tab-key-and-suppress-it)